# No Response from Backend to Frontend - Connection Established but No response received and response is present in logs

Tags: spring-boot, debugging, cors

I'm facing an issue where I'm not receiving any response from the backend to the frontend in my web application. The connection appears to be established, and the backend logs show successful responses. However, the frontend isn't receiving any data. I've confirmed that the API request, response format, and network configuration are all correct. How can I troubleshoot and resolve this issue?

I've been encountering a peculiar problem in my web application's deployment. When I run the application locally, everything works fine, and I receive responses from the backend in postman  without any issues. However, when the same code is deployed to the production environment, I'm not getting any data back from the backend to the frontend.